# Why does the alert pop up more and more times?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm having a confusing problem, but I don't know why it comes up，I have a server level and a client side, they both use socket.io. When a button is clicked, the client side will send a data to the server level, and then the server level will send a feedback to the client side. If the feedback data is 1, the web page will pop up an alert.

---

The problem is that the alert appears once when I click the button for the first time, twice when I click the button for the second time, and three times when I click the button for the third time...
This is the code for the client：

```
function log(names, proto) {
    socket.emit('log',
        JSON.stringify({
            msg: names,
            proto: proto
        })
    )
    socket.on('Existing-user',(e)=>{
        console.log('!')
        if(e===0){
            $(".login").hide()
            $(".content").show()
        }else{
            alert("The username is repeated, please change it.")
        }
    })
}
```

This is the code on the server side：

```
    socket.on('log', function (e) {
        let loginfo = JSON.parse(e);
        if(userlist.includes(loginfo.msg)){
            socket.emit('Existing-user',1)
            console.log('!')
        }else{
            userlist.push(loginfo.msg)
            socket.emit('Existing-user',0)
        }
        console.log(userlist)
    })
```

Comment: That `socket.on()` call will add a listener *every time* the outer `log()` function is called.

Comment: The key word is **add** — previously-added listeners are not removed.